# How to Wait for Angular2 to Handle Dynamic Multiple Http Requests?

Tags: angularjs, http, angular

I know that you can use Observable by calling forkJoin method to wait for multiple http requests to be done like below:

```
getBooksAndMovies() {
    Observable.forkJoin(
        this.http.get('/app/books.json').map((res:Response) => res.json()),
        this.http.get('/app/movies.json').map((res:Response) => res.json())
    ).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.books = data[0]
        this.movies = data[1]
      }
    );
  }
```

However, in my case, I have multiple http posts which they are dynamic like the below code, there are 2 titles, what If I have 100 or 1000 titles. How can I handle such dynamic posts request? Please suggest.

```
createBooksAndMovies() {
  let title = ['Hello', 'World'];
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  let body1 = 'title=' + title[0];
  let body2 = 'title=' + title[1];

    Observable.forkJoin(
        this.http.post('/app/books.json', body1, options).map((res:Response) => res.json()),
        this.http.post('/app/books.json', body2, options).map((res:Response) => res.json())
    ).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.book1 = data[0]
        this.book2 = data[1]
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: In this case, there are 2 titles, what if I have 100 titles, or 1000 titles, How can I handle it? Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use a loop to construct an array of observable sequences:

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) {
    data.push(this.http.post('/app/books.json', bodies[i], options).map((res:Response) => res.json()));
}

Observable.forkJoin(data).subscribe(data => {
    this.books = data;
});
```

In this example I assume that you already have the array of `bodies` constructed dynamically.

Comment: Correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Darin, is there a way to avoid partially saved data if some of the post requests fail?

Comment: @Yang, yes but you need to have some mechanism on the server to rollback requests. The other option is to send the payloads in a single request to the server and let the server side logic take care of this.

Comment: Got it, thank you! I just came across a project using mongodb, which does not provide a better transaction solution. Another motivation is that I tend to implement most of the business logics in frontend instead of backend.