# Parallel HTTP requests with limited concurrency in redux-observable epic using rxjs

Tags: concurrency, rxjs, redux-observable

Have been trying to solve the issue for a while.
Currently I have an array of objects (i call them tiles), which is pretty big.
I have an API endpoint where I should send this objects one by one, this API returns nothing, just status.
I need to send this objects to endpoint in parallel and concurrent manner and when the last of them is successful I should emit some string value which goes to redux store.

```
const tilesEpic =(action$, _state$) => {
    action$.pipe(
        ofType('TILE_ACTION'),
        map(tilesArray => postTilesConcurrently(tilesArray),
        map(someId => someReduxAction(someId),
    )

const postTilesConcurrently = (tilesArray) => {
     const tilesToObservables = tilesArray.map(tile => defer(() => postTile(tile))
     return from(tileToObservables).pipe(mergeAll(concurrencyLimit))
     }
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to emit `someId` from `postTilesConcurrently`, now it triggers action after each request is complete.

Answer (score 2):

`mergeAll()` will subscribe to all sources in parallel but it will also emit each result immediatelly. So instead you could use for example `forkJoin()` (
you could use `toArray()` operator as well).

```
forkJoin(tilesToObservables)
  .pipe(
    map(results => results???), // Get `someId` somehow from results
  );
```

`forkJoin()` will emit just once after all source Observables emit at least once and complete. This means for each source Observable you'll get only the last value it emitted.

Comment: Thank you for reply! Let's say I have one hundred objects and I don't want to make one hundred requests at once. How do I limit it up to, say, 5 requests at a time?

Comment: Then you can use basically what you had. Just after `mergeAll()` use `toArray()` operator that will collect all intermediate `next` notifications and reemit them as one large array after all source Observables complete.

Comment: @DominikDomanski: In addition to @martin's answer, for a buffered request chain (eg. 5 reqs. max in parallel) you could refer my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62872189/6513921. It uses RxJS `from` function with `bufferCount` operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a pitty I did not find it earlier. However I came up with some different code since by the requirements of the task I pass down not the results of the request but some other variable which I got earlier but skipped this part in my example

Answer (score 1):

After Martin's reply I have adjusted my code in order to use `forkJoin`

```
const tilesEpic =(action$, _state$) => {
    action$.pipe(
        ofType('TILE_ACTION'),
        concatMap(tilesArray => postTilesConcurrently(tilesArray),
        map(({someId}) => someReduxAction(someId),
    )

const postTilesConcurrently = (tilesArray) => {
     const tilesToObservables = tilesArray.map(tile => defer(() => postTile(tile))
     return forkJoin({
      images: from(tileToObservables).pipe(mergeAll(concurrencyLimit)),
      someId: from([someId]),
     }
```