# Angular block array of http post consecutive calls

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have and array of Http post in angular

```
peticionesI3.push( ...dataArrayI3.map( data => this.httpService.doPost(url, data, '')) );
```

and call like this

```
return this.httpService.doPost(url, data1, '')
        .pipe(
            switchMap( r => combineLatest( peticionesI2 )),
            switchMap( r => combineLatest( peticionesI3 )),
        )
```

This array, peticionesI3, is too bigger and exceeded the maximum calls allowed.
How can I divide in blocks of 50, and called each block after the previous one is finished?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62872189/6513921. Increase/decrease the `bufferCount` argument to adjust the max no. of parallel calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`combineLatest` will subscribe to all Observable concurrently. Instead you can use `concat` (or eventually `merge` with `concurrency` parameter) to susbcribe to reqeust one by one.

Then to collect all responses into a single array chain it with `toArray()`.

```
import { concat, toArray } from 'rxjs';

...

switchMap(r => concat(...peticionesI3).pipe(toArray())),
```